# LESS - set variables on the client side

Tags: javascript, css, less

I have created a LESS (http://lesscss.org/) version of a simple css grid solution (http://simplegrid.info/. Now I can happily roll my own grid sizes with the server script from LESS (lessc). That's working for me.

For demo purposes I would like to create a HTML page, where I can put the size of the css grid in a textbox and the grid would change dynamically. Beginning of the demo is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8QHNc/

So instead of changing  `@layoutwidth: 720px;` in the `<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" >` section I would like to pass these variables to the LESS interpreter.

Can these be done with the client side usage of less? Can I define global variables or pass them as parameters to less.js somehow?

I am aware that I could do this without the usage of LESS (preferably with jQuery o. sth.) - but I figured since it is already there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if the parser takes any arguments, but why would you refuse to use the built-in javascript evaluation, e.g. adding something like:

```
@layoutwidth: `document.getElementById("inputLayoutWidth") + "px"`;
```

to your Less-Stylesheet. Or, using jQuery, as you proposed:

```
@layoutwidth: `$("#inputLayoutWidth").val() + "px"`;
```

while using an input field like

```
<input type="text" id="inputLayoutWidth" value="720" />
```

and invoke parsing each time the input field is changed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I do not refuse... I actually played with the build in JS evaluation. The problem I was facing was - that the values where ignored... See: http://jsfiddle.net/PmDD3/. The 100px value seems to be always escaped by "". Firebug shows: .box:after {content: "100px";} - but the width of the .box element is always ignored or is not "valid" to the browser.

Comment: Sorry for the late replay, been busy. I forgot the "~" to output the value directly, now it is fixed and takes exactly the specified width in the input box. see [link](http://jsfiddle.net/PmDD3/8/) However, I do not know how to force reparsing the less script client side (without reloading the whole page).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 3.x version of less CSS than u can set them in javascript code as well.

```
 less.modifyVars({
   '@buttonFace': '#5B83AD',
   '@buttonText': '#D9EEF2'
});
```

I don't know if this method is also present in older version of less.