# LESS not calculating jQuery value

Tags: jquery, css, less

I'm trying to get the height of the window in LESS, I've read some articles which imply you can use jQuery in a variable, I.E

```
@height: `$(window).height()`;
```

However I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: JavaScript evaluation error: 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $'
```

It might be good for me too add that I'm running this client side.

Comment: Where have you seen such articles? I don't believe that's possible. Besides, it doesn't make a lot of sense, because the window height can change. The LESS pre-processor performs a one-time translation.

Comment: As @Ponty said, it is impossible to do that in either LESS or SASS. For both compile to CSS and this language is static, not dynamic. It will not spot window's dimensions. However, you can use relative sizes instead (such as `100%`).

Comment: I read it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713474/less-set-variables-on-the-client-side. But I didn't know it can only preform it once, so that's a deal breaker, thanks for responding :).

Comment: Well are you importing jQuery in your page? I've not used LESS client-side (except for a trivial test project) so a facility like this wouldn't be something I had come across. It's still the case that the pre-processor will just run that code while it's translating, and it won't continually update. You might want to look into `calc()`, but it's not supported by many browsers yet (I don't think).

Comment: Not recommended to use LESS compilation in browser on production section of your site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript evaluation error in LESS file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023326/javascript-evaluation-error-in-less-file)